# Javascript occasionally fails using chrome

Tags: javascript

I am using the script below. It works correctly however when using chrome sometimes (2/8) clicks the popup will open without the image it is supposed to be getting. Works flawlessly on IE though. Anyone have an idea why?

```
<center>
   <input onclick="javascript:void(PrintWebPart())" type="button" value="Print Proof of Pricing"/>  
</center> 
<script language="JavaScript">
//Controls which Web Part or zone to print
var WebPartElementID = "ctl00_ctl34_g_5847a9cd_03de_4891_8ec4_ca6dbf3ea45f_FormControl0";
var d= new Date();


//Function to print Web Part
function PrintWebPart()
{
var bolWebPartFound = false;
if (document.getElementById != null)
{
//Create html to print in new window
var PrintingHTML = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';
//Take data from Head Tag
if (document.getElementsByTagName != null)
{
var HeadData= document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD");
if (HeadData.length > 0)
PrintingHTML += HeadData[0].innerHTML;
}
PrintingHTML += '\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n';
var WebPartData = document.getElementById(WebPartElementID);
if (WebPartData != null)
{
PrintingHTML +='<div id="imageDiv">\n</div>\n'
PrintingHTML += WebPartData.innerHTML;
PrintingHTML += "Pricing Date: " +d;
bolWebPartFound = true;
}
else
{
bolWebPartFound = false;
alert ('Cannot Find Web Part');
}
}
PrintingHTML += '\n</BODY>\n</HTML>';
//Open new window to print
if (bolWebPartFound)
{
var PrintingWindow = window.open("","View Proof of Pricing",
"toolbar,width=800,height=600,scrollbars,resizable,menubar");
PrintingWindow.document.open();
PrintingWindow.document.write(PrintingHTML);
PrintingWindow.document.getElementById('imageDiv').setAttribute("align", "center");
PrintingWindow.document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML = '<img src="url" alt="Title" height="170" width="300"/>';

}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh my, it's 2016 – javascript:void()? :)

Comment: first time I use javascript, I actually found most of this online and adapted to my need if theres a better way to do this im open to it

Comment: Remove the javascript:void part and simply call your function inside the HTML quotes: `onclick="PrintWebPart();"`. Also, that function should be called `printWebPart()` instead I.E. start with lower case letter.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just adding the image directly to PrintingHTML?

Comment: yes for some reason if i do it on the printing html the page just comes up blank